# Can this combination of jQuery .append() and .attr() be exploited by XSS attack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

Below I have some code that my code scan tool is marking as vulnerable to XSS attack. It is an AJAX call that can return some untrusted data, which is then used to append a new  to a  dropdown menu. The *value* and the content of the new  is set using the untrusted data from the AJAX call.

It doesn't seem possible to escape out of the .attr() execution context or the .text().  I tried feeding in many attempts to break it but wasn't able to.

Is it possible to exploit this using XSS? Or is my code scanner marking a false positive?

```
$.ajax({                        
    url:'example',
    data: {
        abc : $('#someField').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#dropdown').append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", data.unsafeId)
            .text(data.unsafeText));                                        
    }
});
```

Comment: That's right, setting a `value` attribute (though you should probably use `prop` instead) or setting the `.text` is safe, just like in JS, `elm.value = <anything>` and `elm.textContent = <anything>` is safe. What "code scanner" are you using?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Alright - even though I'm using the .attr() inside the .append() there shouldn't be a way to exploit it right?  I am using IBM Security AppScan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_AppScan